# Can't configure PAM + LDAP on Debian Lenny - Getting error=49 on server logs

Tags: linux, debian, openldap, pam, pam-ldap

I've been migrating some servers and desktops using Ubuntu 10.04 from getting the users from an old OpenLDAP implementation to a newer Centos Active Directory. I haven't had any problems so far, until I reached a Debian Lenny server.

I've set up the server as the others, setting /etc/ldap.conf and /etc/ldap/ldap.conf. However, when I issue "getent passwd", I get nothing from the LDAP server.

Reading the pam_ldap manpage, I realized that /etc/ldap.conf was not an accepted file by pam_ldap -it worked with Ubuntu though-, so I renamed it to /etc/pam_ldap.conf. Same result. However, once I've changed the name of this file, when I login using SSH I get this on the LDAP server logs:

```
[20/Jul/2012:11:19:40 +0200] conn=16501 fd=155 slot=155 connection from x.x.x.50 to 10.1.176.237
[20/Jul/2012:11:19:40 +0200] conn=16501 op=0 BIND dn="uid=ubuntu,ou=Applications,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es" method=128 version=3
[20/Jul/2012:11:19:40 +0200] conn=16501 op=0 RESULT err=0 tag=97 nentries=0 etime=0 dn="uid=ubuntu,ou=applications,ou=citius,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es"
[20/Jul/2012:11:19:40 +0200] conn=16501 op=1 SRCH base="ou=People,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es" scope=2 filter="(uid=jorge.suarez)" attrs=ALL
[20/Jul/2012:11:19:40 +0200] conn=16501 op=1 RESULT err=0 tag=101 nentries=1 etime=0 notes=U
[20/Jul/2012:11:19:40 +0200] conn=16501 op=2 BIND dn="uid=jorge.suarez,ou=People,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es" method=128 version=3
[20/Jul/2012:11:19:40 +0200] conn=16501 op=2 RESULT err=49 tag=97 nentries=0 etime=0
```

The password isn't working. I don't know that could be wrong, anything else seems to be OK. That user/password is working from another clients:

```
[20/Jul/2012:11:29:39 +0200] conn=16528 fd=188 slot=188 connection from x.x.x.224 to 10.1.176.237
[20/Jul/2012:11:29:39 +0200] conn=16528 op=0 BIND dn="uid=ubuntu,ou=Applications,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es" method=128 version=3
[20/Jul/2012:11:29:39 +0200] conn=16528 op=0 RESULT err=0 tag=97 nentries=0 etime=0 dn="uid=ubuntu,ou=applications,ou=citius,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es"
[20/Jul/2012:11:29:39 +0200] conn=16528 op=1 SRCH base="ou=People,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es" scope=2 filter="(uid=jorge.suarez)" attrs=ALL
[20/Jul/2012:11:29:39 +0200] conn=16528 op=1 RESULT err=0 tag=101 nentries=1 etime=0 notes=U
[20/Jul/2012:11:29:39 +0200] conn=16528 op=2 BIND dn="uid=jorge.suarez,ou=People,ou=CITIUS,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es" method=128 version=3
[20/Jul/2012:11:29:39 +0200] conn=16528 op=2 RESULT err=0 tag=97 nentries=0 etime=0 dn="uid=jorge.suarez,ou=people,ou=citius,dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es"
```

I'm using SSHA for storing passwords on the LDAP server. Maybe this is not supported by Debian Lenny?

On pam_ldap.conf, I've set up this, as in all the other servers:

```
# Do not hash the password at all; presume
# the directory server will do it, if
# necessary. This is the default.
pam_password md5
```

Also tried clear, but it didn't work. Anyways, it's weird that issuing getent passwd still gets me no users.

However, if I use pamtest from the package libpam-dotfile to test login, it works.

```
# pamtest ssh jorge.suarez
Trying to authenticate <jorge.suarez> for service <ssh>.
Password: 
Authentication successful.
# pamtest foo jorge.suarez
Trying to authenticate <jorge.suarez> for service <foo>.
Password: 
Authentication successful.
```

But "su" won't work also:

```
# su jorge.suarez
Id. descoñecido: jorge.suarez
```

Just the output from getent passwd :

```
# getent passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/bin/sh
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/sh
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/bin/sh
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/bin/sh
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/bin/sh
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/bin/sh
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/bin/sh
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/bin/sh
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/bin/sh
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/bin/sh
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/bin/sh
libuuid:x:100:101::/var/lib/libuuid:/bin/sh
Debian-exim:x:101:103::/var/spool/exim4:/bin/false
statd:x:102:65534::/var/lib/nfs:/bin/false
sshd:x:104:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
luser:x:1000:1000:Usuario local de Burdeos,,,:/home/luser:/bin/bash
messagebus:x:105:107::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
sge-admin:x:1001:1001:Administrador do SGE,,,:/home/cluster/sge-admin:/bin/bash
ntp:x:107:110::/home/ntp:/bin/false
haldaemon:x:108:111:Hardware abstraction layer,,,:/var/run/hald:/bin/false
vde2-net:x:109:114::/var/run/vde2:/bin/false
uml-net:x:110:115::/home/uml-net:/bin/false
polkituser:x:111:116:PolicyKit,,,:/var/run/PolicyKit:/bin/false
Debian-pxe:x:113:65534:Dummy user for Debian pxe package,,,:/home/Debian-pxe:/bin/false
```

Nscd was stopped from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've migrated to libpam-ldapd and now everything works.

I only had to redo the configuration on a new file called ''/etc/nslcd.conf''.
libpam-ldapd is much better than libpam-ldap.

The most interesting thing is that it relies on a daemon, so you can just call the daemon with debug parameters (''nslcd -d'') and take a look if something is not working as expected, if there's some caveat on the configuration, etc.

Ubuntu 10.04 has libpam-ldapd 0.7.x that lacks some interesting options. Better go for a 0.8.x by using a PPA. Debian Squeeze already has the 0.8.x version, and I've installed it from there on Lenny without problems.